# UCanAccess "unexpected token" error when the alias contains certain characters

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

UCanAccess SQL execution error when the alias contains some characters.

**Env:**
1. UCanAccess-4.0.4.
2. Windows 10. 
3. Java language.

**Reference Image:**

[image: SQL Image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. It has been reproduced using console.bat:

```
UCanAccess>SELECT SUM(category_id) AS `sum(categories abc:category_id)` FROM `categories abc`;
UCanAccess>UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected token: CATEGORIES

UCanAccess>SELECT SUM(category_id) AS `sumcategories abc:category_id)` FROM `categories abc`;

·--------------------------------·
| sumcategories abc:category_id) |
·--------------------------------·
|                             47 |
·--------------------------------·


UCanAccess>SELECT SUM(category_id) AS `sum(categoriesabc:category_id)` FROM `categories abc`;

·--------------------------------·
| sum(categoriesabc:category_id) |
·--------------------------------·
|                             47 |
·--------------------------------·
```

Also worth noting is that if we rename the table from `categories abc` to `categories` then the query with the original column alias works

```
UCanAccess>SELECT SUM(category_id) AS `sum(categories abc:category_id)` FROM `categories`;

·---------------------------------·
| sum(categories abc:category_id) |
·---------------------------------·
|                              47 |
·---------------------------------·
```

The issue has been reported to the UCanAccess development team.